# Can't close my open trades in MetaTrader Terminal 4 Strategy Tester

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I am trying to code my EA where if my close conditions are met, I want my EA to close all the open trades ( there are potentially more than 1 open trades ).

Here is my code for the closing trade section and when I run it through the Strategy Tester, I noticed it doesn't close my trades.

```
 Total=0;                                     // Amount of orders
 for(int i=1; i<=OrdersTotal(); i++)          // Loop through orders
 {
  if (OrderSelect(i-1,SELECT_BY_POS)==true) // If there is the next one
    {                                       // Analyzing orders:
     if (OrderSymbol()!=Symb)continue;      // Another security
      Total++;                               // Counter of market orders
    }
 }   


   while(true)                                  // Loop of closing orders
 {

  if (OrderType()==0 && Close_Buy_Condition==true)                // Order Buy is opened & Close Buy Condition is true
    {                                       
   for (c=Total-1; c>=0; c--)
    { 
     RefreshRates();                        // Refresh rates
     Ans=OrderClose(OrderTicket(),Lot,Bid,Slippage);      // Closing Buy
    }
    }


  if (OrderType()==1 && Close_Sell_Condition==true)                // Order Sell is opened & Close Sell Condition is true
    {                                       
   for (d=Total-1; d>=0; d--)
    {
     RefreshRates();                        // Refresh rates
     Ans=OrderClose(OrderTicket(),Lot,Ask,Slippage);      // Closing Sell

    }
    }

  break;                                    // Exit while
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where do you set value for `Ask`, `Bid` and `Lot` variables. But they've to change when you loop through your open positions.

You can try this function to close all positions:

```
bool CloseAllPositions()
  {
   double total;
   int cnt;
   while(OrdersTotal()>0)
     {
      //  Close pending orders first, you can remove this section if you don't want pending orders to be deleted
      total=OrdersTotal();
      for(cnt=total-1; cnt>=0; cnt--)
        {
         if(OrderSelect(cnt,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES))
           {
            switch(OrderType())
              {
               case OP_BUYLIMIT  :OrderDelete(OrderTicket()); break;
               case OP_SELLLIMIT :OrderDelete(OrderTicket()); break;
               case OP_BUYSTOP   :OrderDelete(OrderTicket()); break;
               case OP_SELLSTOP  :OrderDelete(OrderTicket()); break;
              }
           }
        }

      // then close opened orders 
      total=OrdersTotal();
      for(cnt=total-1; cnt>=0; cnt--)
        {
         if(OrderSelect(cnt,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES))
           {
            switch(OrderType())
              {
               case OP_BUY:
                  if (Close_Buy_Condition==true) {
                    OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(),MODE_BID),3,Violet);
                  }
                  break;

               case OP_SELL:
                  if (Close_Sell_Condition==true) {
                    OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(),MODE_ASK),3,Violet);
                  }
                  break;
              }
           }
        }
     }
   return true;
  }
```

Edit:

if you don't want to deal with pending orders at all, use this code instead of `OrdersTotal()`:

```
int GetNumOpenPositions() {
    int total = OrdersTotal();

    double OpenBuyOrders = 0, OpenSellOrders = 0, PendBuys =0, PendSells =0;
     for( i=0;i<total;i++)       
       {
         OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS );
        if ( OrderSymbol() == Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber() == MagicNumber)
             {
               int type = OrderType();

               if (type == OP_BUY )       {OpenBuyOrders=OpenBuyOrders+1;}
               if (type == OP_SELL )      {OpenSellOrders=OpenSellOrders+1;}
               if (type == OP_BUYSTOP )   {PendBuys=PendBuys+1;}
               if (type == OP_SELLSTOP )  {PendSells=PendSells+1;}

             }
        }
       return (OpenBuyOrders + OpenSellOrders);
   }
```

Then total orders would be

Comment: Hi. It seems to be stuck in a loop. Is there a missing line somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: It will stuck in a loop while OrdersTotal() > 0. Be aware that OrdersTotal() will return number of open + pending positions, if you don't close pending orders OrdersTotal() will be > 0 and you should change the conditions a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: ( The values of **`Ask`**, **`Bid`** are MetaTrader Terminal 4 platform maintained system variables, with values being updated whenever an FX-Market-Event appears ( be it simulated from Strategy Tester or stream-sourced from the live Market ). ) The proposed code is flawed, as it ignores many colliding states, that happen in real trading. You might want to wish to re-design the code, so that it does not create a false illusion to the O/P altogether with better handling such error-states in context of where MT4-Server side responds with an XTO/non-XTO  rejection reason. Anyway - Happy Trading!